# Swing issue: drawing rectangles over the pdf image and keep their size and positions consistent when zooming in and out

Tags: java, swing

I have a rather pressing question in regards to Swing, which I haven't touched for many years.

I have a code that allows the user to draw different rectangles on the pdf document (contained within `JPanel`). I draw them, move them, resize them, select them, and even write text on them. What I can't do is to keep them consistent when I zoom the document. As the document gets bigger, the rectangles I've drawn stay at the same position and the same size.

I was wondering if there's a relatively easy logic to track the zooming level and, most importantly, update the rectangles accordingly. I can retrieve zoom factor, it's a float, but, unfortunately, I'm using `Rectangle` object, which uses `int` for `x`, `y`, `height`, and `width`.  It will be a hassle to convert it to `Rectangle.Float`, and I wanted to save it for a last resort.

I've tried to use `AffineTransform`, but I'm not quite familiar with it, for some reason I'm getting the wrong coordinates for `y`. Can anyone explain to me:

1. What's the best way to control the Rectangle object, as the pdf document gets zoomed in and out?
2. If `AffineTransform` is the best way, how should I handle it (maybe there's a link to a good explanation, if so - I couldn't find it)?

This is the only issue I've been struggling with and it's getting a bit frustrating now.

Comment: You're saying that you're getting the wrong results, but I don't see any code. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scale using an [AffineTransform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html):

1. Get the transform **T** of the `Graphics` object **G**
2. Create an AffineTransform object **A**
3. Set the scale of **A**
4. Set the transform of the **G** to **A**
5. Draw the shapes
6. Set the transform of **G** back to **T**

Translated into code - assuming `scale` is the value to scale by:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr){
    super.paintComponent(gr);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
    AffineTransform prevTransform = g.getTransform();
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform(prevTransform);
    at.scale(scale, scale); 
    g.setTransform(at);
    g.drawRect(...);
    g.setTransform(prevTransform); 
}
```